# CO2 conversion to a harmless gas like oxygen

Tags: purification

I am doing some research about indoor purifiers and I was wondering if there is any approach to purify co2 or convert it to harmless gases like oxygen just like what plants do.

Comment: You could use [sodium peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_peroxide): $\ce{2Na2O2 +2 CO2 -> 2Na2CO3 + O2}$

Comment: Plants do the job pretty well: why not use them? Besides carbon dioxide isn't *harmful* in the quantities normally found in the atmosphere (you produce it when you breathe). Only when there is a lot more than normal levels does it become a problem for living things which have adapted to low levels because they produce it.

Answer (score 1):

Submarines currently use NaOH/Ca(OH)2 to absorb CO2. They generate O2 separately either from gas tanks or by electrolysis of water. Peroxides seem attractive at first, but they are a fire hazard and you don't want fire on a submarine. British subs are using Zeolite. The role of zeolite isn't to deal with CO2, but to remove the smell of volitile organic compounds (of dirty socks, so to say). Air is first dried and purified.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?